# How to fix indentation on pre and code tag?

Tags: html

When using the pre and code tags in HTML, when you press enter to add a new line of code, the code that shows on the code-block on your webpage becomes extremely indented. The only solution I know how to fix this issue is to comment out the white spice inside of the code tag, but it seems like it's a bad practice. Is there a way to fix this? I still want to be able to indent, but I don't want the indents to extend outside of the actual code tag.

I want my code to look like this, but it gives me weird output:

```
                <pre>
                    <code style='padding-top: 12px; margin: 10px 0px 0px 10px;' class="language-html">
                        &lt;nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-brand serif"&gt;
                            &lt;div class="container-fluid"&gt;
                                &lt;div class="diagonal"&gt;
                    </code>
                </pre>
```

EDIT:

**Here's the output I want**:
[Good Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17yX4.png)

**Here's the output I get (I do not like because of all the extra space on the left side)**:
[Bad Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lbu2z.png)

The only way to get the output I want is to do this, and as you can see, it ruins my indentations, but it removes all of the extra space on the left side. I want the indentation to be normal, not like this:

```
                <pre>
                    <code style='padding-top: 12px; margin: 10px 0px 0px 10px;' class="language-html">
&lt;nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-brand serif"&gt;
    &lt;div class="container-fluid"&gt;
        &lt;div class="diagonal"&gt;
                    </code>
                </pre>
```

Comment: Why are you using `pre` if you don't want to preserve whitespace?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre

Comment: If I remove the pre tag, the indents go away. I don't want to remove my ability to indent on the code block, I just want to remove the excessive indentation when making a new line. If you look at the commented out part on the 3rd line, there are 16 characters. If I uncomment, then it indents to 16 characters. How do I only preserve indentation within the pre tag, not outside of it?

Comment: @jchillin111 The `<pre>` tag already preserve indentation inside the content of the `<pre>` tag. That's the only purpose of this tag. It is not clear what exactly the problem is. When you have a space inside the `<pre>` tag you get that space (and a monospace font) in your output. Please [edit] your question on how your output of your HTML should look like and what output you currently get.

Comment: @jchillin111 Do you accept javascript solutions?

Comment: I edited it, let me know if it makes more sense or not. EDIT: I accept all solutions, JS included